NetBeans not letting me create a project
i have netbeans 21 and jdk 17.
when trying to create a java with maven application, it says "finding feature", configuring java cluster, it loads, then disappears.
i have waited and nothing happens. the only option is to click cancel.



i tried reinstalling JDK and NetBeans but still same outcome. also tried with jdk22, same issue.

I was having the same problem and could solve it!
Go to local disc C -> Users -> yourUser and there delete the ".m2" folder and thats it :)
I found it in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qLDHrIIYhg&list=LL&index=1
